# When I use `budo index.js --open --live` everytime I see same thing .see already what was in the browser

Tags: node.js

When I use

> budo index_editor_java_02.js --open --live

every time I see same thing ,even I changed

> index_editor_java_02.js

nothing happen and I see already what was in the browser at

> http://192.168.5.10:9966/

before.

so How should I changed the js file makes changes in browser

same thing same port.non attention to what is in javascript file.

I think in first loading something registered in system so for times after that it could not change that.but which system .where and how we could change it is my question.

Regards

Comment: did you install budo globally? `npm install budo -g`

Comment: I do that.modify the js file.budo show errors but browse in browser the same as before any modification.